# Why is the past participle of the French « lire » « lu », but « rire » « ri »?

Tags: etymology, phonology, historical-linguistics, latin, french

Phonologically,« lire » and « rire »  sound like a minimal pair, with the first letter as the only difference.  So what might explain the difference between their « participes passé »?
Their etymons are Latin.

**Reply to comment by user 'sumelic':**  I'm inexperienced in Latin; so please feel free to edit.

[*lire*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lire#French) originates from [*legō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lego#Latin), whose active present infinitive is *legere*.

[*rire*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rire#Etymology) originates from [*rīdeō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rideo#Latin), whose active present infinitive is *rīdēre*.

Comment: Nothing explains it to us; theoretically it's the result of billions of uses over millions of speakers over a millennium or so, but in fact nobody was keeping track because everything was written in Latin. That's the way facts are -- they just are, and explanations if any come much later.

Comment: The -u ending of many past participles in French seems to be of uncertain etymology: https://books.google.com/books?id=UwuyyR7cHdIC&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=etymology+french+past+participles+in+u&source=bl&ots=_n8MEWDxWC&sig=nN3Gs3PAOrLNIL2gXAB8YD_HvJ4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBzgKahUKEwjR25WJzcPHAhVPKogKHScnAF4#v=onepage&q=etymology%20french%20past%20participles%20in%20u&f=false

Comment: @sumelic Thanks. Which form do you mean by `past participle`? Please edit my post.

Comment: The past participle (also called _supine_, though that name refers a different construction using the same verb-form) is the fourth Latin principal part (_lego, legere, lexi, **lectum**_), with a **-to* suffix from PIE, like the cognate Greek "_to_-participle". In English the past participle is the third principal part (_go, went, gone_). You can look them up yourself; that's why dictionaries give principal parts. English often borrows different words from different verb forms of the same verb, like _sum, essence,_ and _future_, all from the same Latin verb.

Comment: @jlawler. Do you really think English "sum" (as in "sum total") is borrowed from Latim "sum" ("I am")?

Comment: No idea, frankly. I didn't look it up, I was just reaching for different stems of _esse_. Feel free to look it up yourself if you like.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: I want to say that this question is not at all bad.

In Latin, lego, legere, lēgī, lēctus “to read” belongs to the third conjugation, while rīdeo, ridēre, rīsī, rīsus “to laugh” belongs to the second conjugation. As you can see, they are completely different in each of the four principal parts. So it is not so much a question of similar verbs developing differently as of very different verbs becoming more similar. Languages work in both ways.

Latin had a fair number of verbs with a perfect participle in –ūtus, for example secūtus from sequor “to follow”. In Romance languages this form has spread to a large number of different verbs, including French venu, Italian venuto, where it replaced the ending of Latin ventus, but this has not by any means happened to all verbs. For example, it affected lego, but not rīdeo.

Comment: Note that both _lectus_ and _ventus_ have that CC cluster you can put additional vowels in but with _risus_, not so much (there would have to be some crazy transient form like _ridutus_).

Comment: Hmm, is a Vulgar *–ūtus* form really the explanation for the *lu* form in French? In Italian, the past participle of *leggere* is *letto*, directly from Latin *lectum*, although I don't know if that could be a more learned form that ultimately replaced a popular \**leggiuto*.